# html5/javascript game running slow in ie8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

We have made a game in html/javascript. There's unfortunately a lot of secrecy around the project, so I can't disclose much code.

However the essence is that it runs extremely well on all browsers, except ie. through using the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` tag; now the only problem is ie8, which the game NEEDS to be compatible with. I know it has little html5 integration, but the game actually works, except it's horribly slow.

Keep in mind, ie9 and ie10 were very slow before using the tag as well. The game is in n sense advanced or anything. So I was wondering if anyone knew what could cause issues like these?

I'll try to put some obfuscated code here, keep in mind though that it's not the entire code, just the main loop:

```
    // Global constants:
var PLAYGROUND_WIDTH    = 1000;
var PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT    = 1000;
var REFRESH_RATE        = 30;

//Constants for the gameplay
var smallStarSpeed        = 1; //pixels per frame

var mediumStarSpeed       = 3; //pixels per frame

var bigStarSpeed          = 5; //pixels per frame

var percent = 1;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// --                      the main declaration:                     --
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

$(function(){
//Calculate playground width and height:
PLAYGROUND_WIDTH = $(window).width() - 20;
PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT = $(window).height() - 20;

//Calculate Layour for responsive Design.
//Calculate Area:


// Animations declaration: 
// The background:    

var DM = new DeckManager;
var IM = new ImageManager;

IM.Create("Image1");


//DEBUG: Loading images for demo, this should be done using the image manager in the actual game.
var background1 = new $.gameQuery.Animation({
    imageURL: "http://gamequeryjs.com/demos/3/background1.png"});
var background2 = new $.gameQuery.Animation({
    imageURL: "http://gamequeryjs.com/demos/3/background2.png"}); 
var background3 = new $.gameQuery.Animation({
    imageURL: "http://gamequeryjs.com/demos/3/background3.png"});
var background4 = new $.gameQuery.Animation({
    imageURL: "http://gamequeryjs.com/demos/3/background4.png"});
var background5 = new $.gameQuery.Animation({
    imageURL: "http://gamequeryjs.com/demos/3/background5.png"});
var background6 = new $.gameQuery.Animation({
    imageURL: "http://gamequeryjs.com/demos/3/background6.png"});



    var Face = new Array();
    IM.Load("image2");
    IM.Load("image3");
    IM.Load("image4");
            IM.Load("image5");


            var resizeTimer;

//Event to handle resizing
//This event should fire under any circimstance, except when safari is NOT maximized, and windows resolution is changed (WTF?)
$(window).resize(function () 
{
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(Resized, 100);
});

//Actual Resizing Event
function Resized() 
{
    //Your function goes here


    //Calculate playground width and height:
    PLAYGROUND_WIDTH = $(window).width() - 20;
    PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT = $(window).height() - 20;

    //Calculate Layout for responsive Design.
};


// Initialize the game:
$("#playground").playground({
    height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT, 
    width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
    keyTracker: true,
    mouseTracker: true});

// Initialize the background
$.playground()
    .addGroup("background", {width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
                             height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT})
    .addSprite("background1", {animation: background1, 
                               width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
                               height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT})  
    .addSprite("background2", {animation: background2,
                               width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
                               height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT, 
                               posx: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH})
    .addSprite("background3", {animation: background3, 
                               width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
                               height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT})
    .addSprite("background4", {animation: background4, 
                               width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
                               height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT, 
                               posx: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH})
    .addSprite("background5", {animation: background5, 
                               width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
                               height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT})
    .addSprite("background6", {animation: background6, 
                               width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
                               height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT, 
                               posx: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH})
    $("#background").addSound(bgmusic);
//Setup obects so they can be reached randomly
var Vals = new Array();
var Vals2 = new Array();
var Turned = 0;
var TurnedMax = 2;

//This will ensure that two cards of each are added to the deck
//This function will be handled by the imagemanager at later stages.
for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfCards; ++i)
{
    Vals[i] = Math.floor(i/2);
}

Vals2[0]=3;

DM.Create(Vals, Vals2, NumberOfCards, 1);

//Generate the actual object

    $.playground()
    .addGroup("object", {width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, 
                             height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT})

for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfCards+1; ++i)
{
    //Generate unique ID for the card
    var name = "object"+i;

    val = DM.Pushobject();

    //Add the actual card to the playground, we spawn them in a responsive awy based on the resolution of the game.
    $("#object").addSprite(name, {animation: IM.GetBack(), width: 208, height: 303, posx: (i%(Math.ceil(noc*Ratio))) *SpaceX + SpaceX - 104 + LastYOff * (  i>=  (NumberOfCards + NumberOfCardsBonus) - ((NumberOfCards + NumberOfCardsBonus)%(Math.ceil(noc*Ratio))) ) , posy: Math.floor( i / (Math.ceil(noc*Ratio))  ) * SpaceY + SpaceY - 152 });//

    //Add a class to the object, this, does nothing except make us able to search for objects with the same class later in the code.
    $("#"+name).addClass("object");

    //Create the actual class for the object, this will add logic to the object.
    $("#"+name)[0].Cards = new Cards($("#"+name));
    $("#"+name)[0].Cards.Create(val, IM.GetImage(val), IM.GetImage(3), IM.GetBack(), DM.LastBonus(), Scale);


    //Add a mousedown event for the card, this mousedown will be run in the main
    //environment rather than the class environment to make sure that we have access
    //to all the data we need access to.
    $("#"+name).mousedown(function(e)
    {
        var Ready = 0;
        $(".object").each(function()
        {
            if (this.object.visible && (this.object.Turning==true || this.object.FlippedV==true))
            {
                Ready++;
            }
        });
        //Find all the objects with the tag/class card.
        $(".object").each(function()
        {
            //Check if the mouse clicked the object, if it's still part of the game, and if it has not been flipped.
            if (e.clickedobject
            && Ready<TurnedMax)
            {
                //Run the clicked event for the card, this will start events etc.
                this.object.Clicked();
                //Increase the turned counter, if we have turned the correct amount of objectto be compared
                //then compare them.
                if (this.Cards.Bonus == false)
                {
                    Turned++;
                    if (Turned==TurnedMax)
                    {
                        //We have turned the amount of object needed
                        //Find out which value the first object has, and use this as a base to compare if cards match.
                        //Also instantiate a counter for the amount of cards actually matching.
                        //It's done this way if you want a variable number of object needed for a match.
                        var Correct = this.object.value;
                        var CorrectAmount = 0;
                        $(".object").each(function()
                        {
                            //For each card, if they are flipped, are not going into hiding/deletion, and has the
                            //Correct value, increase the counter for the number of objects matching.
                            if (this.object.Flipped == true && this.object.Hiding==0 && this.object.value == Correct)
                                CorrectAmount++;

                        });

                        //If we have a correct match
                        if (CorrectAmount==TurnedMax)
                        {
                            $(".object").each(function()
                            {
                                //Foreach object that is flipped and not in hiding, delete them (aka. yay, you got a match).
                                if (this.object.Flipped==true && this.object.Hiding==0)
                                    this.object.SetVisible(false);
                            });
                        }

                        $(".object").each(function()
                        {
                            //Foreach objectthat was not in hiding and was not part of the match, unflip them again.
                            if (this.object.Flipped==true && this.object.Hiding==0)
                            this.object.Hide();
                        });

                        Turned=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });


}

// this sets the id of the loading bar (NOT USED YET):
$.loadCallback(function(percent){
        $("#loadingBar").width(400*percent);
  });
//initialize the start button
$("#startbutton").click(function(){
    $.playground().startGame(function(){
        $("#welcomeScreen").remove();
    });
})


//This is for the background animation (DEBUG)
$("#playground").registerCallback(function(){

$("#background1").x(($("#background1").x() + smallStarSpeed +PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) % (2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) - PLAYGROUND_WIDTH);
$("#background2").x(($("#background2").x() + smallStarSpeed +PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) % (2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) - PLAYGROUND_WIDTH);

$("#background3").x(($("#background3").x() + mediumStarSpeed +PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) % (2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) - PLAYGROUND_WIDTH);
$("#background4").x(($("#background4").x() + mediumStarSpeed +PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) % (2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) - PLAYGROUND_WIDTH);

$("#background5").x(($("#background5").x() + bigStarSpeed +PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) % (2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) - PLAYGROUND_WIDTH);
$("#background6").x(($("#background6").x() + bigStarSpeed +PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) % (2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) - PLAYGROUND_WIDTH);


//Basic Game Engine!!

$(".object").each(function()
{
    //For each card, perform their step event.
    this.object.Step();
});

}, REFRESH_RATE);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some obfuscated code?

Comment: ie8 doesn't support html5, then again html5 is basically just a useless buzzword :) we are gonna need some code or a demo, but it's pretty much gonna come down to optimizing the poop out of it. have a look at http://calendar.perfplanet.com maybe you'll find an article that fits your needs

Comment: Not answering your question, but why `IE=9`, not `IE=edge`?

Comment: btw this will force each browser to work in its native mode: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;IE=10;IE=9;IE=8"> ..or edge like @Passerby says. Your code will force IE11/10 to work as IE9, not great. And no, you can't force IE8 to behave as IE9 ..would be too easy :) Well, there are polyfills, but they help with css/js compatibility, not performance.

Comment: I see that you are selecting a lot classnames with the jQuery selector. This process is slower at IE because it lacks of the native `getElementsByClassName()` js-function. It's very slow at IE if you compare it towards other modern browsers.

Comment: @KarelG: IE8 and higher *do* support `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()`, which means it's perfectly possible in IE to read class names without a significant performance hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you're using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`.

That's is unlikely to be helpful in any way at all.

**It will have no effect at all in IE9 or IE8.**

It will be having an effect in IE10 and IE11, but that effect will be to pull the browser down into backward-compatibility mode, which basically means that you're telling IE10 and higher to switch off some of their newer features and pretend to be IE9.

There's really no point in that at all; in fact, it's probably doing more harm than good, so I recommend removing that line of code entirely.

If you must have an `X-UA-Compatible` flag, the only sensible value for it is `IE=edge`. This will force all IE versions to use the best mode they have available. That's the default anyway in most cases, but it might help in the few cases where the default is something else.

But the real problem you're complaining about here is performance, and I can tell you categorically that this is entirely unrelated to the `X-UA-Compatible` flag -- as I say, the way you have it set won't have any effect on IE8 at all anyway, so it's not that which is slowing things down.

Ultimately, your problem with IE8 may boil down to the simple fact that it is just a much *much* slower browser than later versions. It is possible that you may simply not be able to get IE8 to perform well enough to achieve what you want.

IE9 and IE10 are much better, so you should be able to get reasonable performance from them with a bit of tweaking, so your best hope would probably be to do some performance tuning.

And the best bet for performance testing is to upgrade to IE11, which has *much* better dev tools than IE10, including some really good tools for analysing your site's performance.

Performance tuning is big topic in itself (out of scope for this answer), but the ultimate goal is to work out what is causing your biggest bottlenecks, and fix those. In most cases there's generally just one or two major issues that hold everything up, and dealing with them is usually sufficient to make the difference.

So my advice is: Download IE11 and try out the new performance testing features in the new dev tools. Hopfully that'll be enough to get you started, but if you still can't find the problem, try asking a more specific question about whay a particular bit of your code is slow.

One other thing I would suggest is maybe to try reducing your use of libraries like jQuery.

jQuery is incredibly useful, but it does have a performance impact. Try switching to native Javascript where possible.

And where you can't, try reducing the number of times you make the same call. For example:

```
$("#background1").x(($("#background1").x() + smallStarSpeed +PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) % (2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) - PLAYGROUND_WIDTH);
```

This calls `$("#background1")` twice. Do this instead:

```
var $bg1 = $("#background1");
$bg1.x(($bg1.x() + smallStarSpeed +PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) % (2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH) - PLAYGROUND_WIDTH);
```

Better yet, if you can do it with `document.getElementByTagName` rather than jQuery, you'll save yourself even more performance.

I also notice that you're repeating some calculations in that code. Obviously, if you can tidy that up to reduce the repeats, it will also help.

I hope that's given you some directions to think.

Comment: wow, thanks that was an amazing anwser.
Tidying up the code will be done at some later point, that's for sure.

About the meta tag, the stranbge thing is that both IE10 and IE9 performed horribly until we added that tag, from that point on, they were able to run the game with no problems whatsoever.

I will look into using less JQuery when i'm able to, i'm not too good with the language yet, but i'll look into it!

Thanks for pointing out the ie 11 development tools for me, that might really come in handy!

Comment: You talk about repeating calculations, i can't see excactly where that is done (Except if you refer to repeating calls)

Comment: Re the meta tag: Possibly, if you were testing locally, IE might have been set to default to compat mode (typically IE7 compat. You can check the config setting using the *Tools->Compatibility View Settings* menu option). This would indeed cause problems, and setting `IE=9` would appear to fix it. However, you should use `IE=edge` instead, otherwise you're still going to be causing issues for IE10 and higher. See my [related answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754267/why-ie8-is-in-ie7-mode-variable-ie-7/7754540#7754540) for a bit more info on this.

Comment: Re repeated calculations: There are six almost identical lines there. They may not be completely identical, but they're surely close enough that you can do some refactoring to reduce repetition? If nothing else, `2 * PLAYGROUND_WIDTH` is being done six times in quick succession and should be pre-calculated. I'd be willing to bet that there's more could be done there, but it depends if this is the bottleneck or not (I haven't had time to analyse your code in depth). The bottleneck will probably be in code that is called repeatedly throughout the game, so that's what you need to focus on.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Those lines you pointed out were actually debuggin code, so that's why i didn't check them through (Or made them in a viable way), but it's great you use hte as examples, because now i have an idea of what to look for! Thanks a lot for the help really!

Answer (score 0):

Put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >` 
in your html head tag and try. Switching the compatibility view on turns IE into IE8 rendering.

http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie08/chrome28/ff22.html