# Web page is rendering only in compatibility view in IE8+ browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, internet-explorer

I am using html and JQuery. The problem is the page is rendered in compatibility view only. How can i make it work normally without clicking on browser compatibility view button?

Please find below my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!--[if lt IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/styles.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/js/myjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Am i using any wrong version of JQuery? is there any problem with JQuery versions?

How can i get it working in IE7+ versions `without switching to compatibility view mode`? It works fine in Fire Fox. `If i move IE conditional statements to top of html page then it works in IE also without switching to compatibility view mode.`

Thanks!

Comment: Use the developers tools to see the javascript console and tell us if it shows any error.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754267/why-ie8-is-in-ie7-mode-variable-ie-7/7754540#7754540

Comment: By chance, is it an intranet website?

Comment: Yes...it is intranet site..

Comment: What does the `taglib` thingy do? It doesn't generate any HTML content, I hope?